# Spark Submit Does Not Fail If The SQL Added to Run It Has a Query That Fails

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, spark-submit

I have a spark submit command that is given a .sql file with 10 consecutive queries in it to run.

If one of the queries fails due to syntax error or table not found issue, the spark submit command still succeeds and doesn't throw any error.

When I give `yarn application -status <application_id>` command the output says:

> Final-State : SUCCEEDED

How do I make spark submit fail if one of the queries fails so that it shows the job didn't actually complete successfully?

I tried using

```
spark-submit --rest of the jars and configs (This works fine and runs the sql file)
if $ -ne 0
      exit 1
else 
  <send email commands>
```

I also tried to generate `yarn application -status <application_id>`
to grep FAILED status indication from there so I could make the job exit 1 (fail).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mark Spark Job as Failed in Yarn UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40347471/mark-spark-job-as-failed-in-yarn-ui)

Comment: Have you tried using beeline instead of Spark submit if you just want to run sql files?